# Divisible torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove that for any divisible torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module $V$,
this map 
$$f:\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\otimes_E\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},V)\longrightarrow V\mbox{ defined by }
f((q+\mathbb{Z})\otimes g)=g(q+\mathbb{Z})$$
is an isomorphism, where tensor is taken over the ring $E=\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$.

It is easy to prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, but I couldn't prove that $f$ is bijective. Are there any special properties for divisible torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-modules that help in proving that the above map $f$ is bijective?

Comment: How do you know it is bijective?

Comment: It is stated in Robert wisbaur paper(static modules and equivlances) in page 8 that this map is an isomorphism

Comment: Stated without proof? Have you tried to find the proof in other references?

Comment: No without proof

Comment: There are 32 references in this paper

Comment: I think you just added an important detail to the question.

Comment: In case it is interesting I have a proof of the surjectivity that I'm unable to upgrade to a full proof. Every element $v$ such that $nv=0$ is the image of $(\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb{Z})\otimes \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is any extension to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of the map $\mathbb{Z}/n\to V$ sending $1+n\mathbb{Z}$ to $v$. The extension exists since $V$ is divisible and hence injective.

Comment: Outline of proof: Everything breaks into a direct sum of the $p$-torsion parts over all primes $p$, so it's enough to prove it after localizing at $p$. Now $V$ is a direct limit of its ``cofinitely generated'' subs, i.e. submodules which look like a sum of finitely many $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$'s. Direct limits commute with everything, so it's basically enough to prove it for $V\cong \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$. But here it's just the isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{End(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)} End(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @KevinVentullo: The end of your argument has a slight "cheat": the tensor product begins as one over $\mathbf{Z}$, and one has to directly compute (by various elementary means) the endomorphism ring to see that it collapses away in the tensor product (so tensoring *over* the endomorphism ring is a red herring).

Comment: @KevinVentullo: The step where you say direct limits "commute with everything" also has a small gap insofar as moving a direct limit out of the *second* variable of a Hom is not a generally valid thing, so its validity in the present setting (which is true) does require an argument (e.g., via Pontryagin duality or other means).

Comment: @user76758 I'm not sure I understand your first comment. The author says the tensor is taken over $End(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. For your second comment, you're right, I should remark that the image of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ under any homomorphism lands inside a cofinitely generated sub.

Comment: @KevinVentullo: Whoops, I had not noticed the last sentence of the question. Since that endomorphism ring is $\widehat{Z}$, as noted by Strickland, for the purpose of tensoring against a torsion module it could just as well be $\mathbf{Z}$ (as I had been thinking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, consider an element $v\in V$.  As $V$ is torsion we can choose $n$ such that $n!v=0$.  For $k\leq n$ put $u_k=(n!/k!)v$.  Then choose $u_k$ for $k>n$ inductively with $ku_k=u_{k-1}$ (which is possible because $V$ is divisible).  There is then a unique homomorphism $\phi\colon\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to V$ such that $\phi([1/k!])=u_k$ for all $k$, and $f([1/n!]\otimes \phi)=v$.  This shows that $f$ is surjective.

Now consider an element $\alpha\in\ker(f)$.  As $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the union of the cyclic subgroups generated by elements of the form $[1/n!]$, we see that $\alpha$ can be written as $[1/n!]\otimes\phi$ for some $\phi\colon\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to V$ with $\phi([1/n!])=0$.  Now multiplication by $n!$ gives a surjective endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, whose kernel is generated by $[1/n!]$.  It follows easily that $\phi=n!\psi$ for some $\psi$, and thus that $\alpha=n![1/n!]\otimes\psi=0$.  Thus, $f$ is also injective.

The above argument shows that the composite
$$ \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},V) \to 
   \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\text{End}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})} \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},V) \to V
$$
is an isomorphism, and it follows easily that both of the maps involved are isomorphisms.  One can also see more directly that the first map is an isomorphism, using the standard fact that $\text{End}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is the profinite completion of the integers, together with the obvious fact that the first tensor factor $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion group.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} = \varinjlim (1/n) \mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{Z}$ and $V = \varinjlim V[n]$ (as $V$ is torsion), it suffices to show that for $n > 0$ the natural map ${\rm{Hom}}(\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z},V)/(n) \rightarrow V[n]$ defined by evaluation at $1/n \bmod \mathbf{Z}$ is an isomorphism (as then with a small diagram chase we can pass to the direct limit over more divisible $n$ to conclude).

But $V$ is an injective abelian group (as $V$ is divisible), so applying ${\rm{Hom}}(\cdot, V)$ to the exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow (1/n)\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{Z} \rightarrow \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} \stackrel{n}{\rightarrow} \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
yields exactly the desired isomorphism.

[In effect, this is a reformulation of the same argument as in Neil Strickland's answer, as I am masking some calculations implicit in the proof that divisible abelian groups are injective. I am also tacitly using that $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ is the endomorphism ring of $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$, so tensoring over it against a torsion module is the same as tensoring over $\mathbf{Z}$.]